# Android Custom Array Adapter getView taking wrong id (the next one in the listview)

Tags: android, listview, adapter

**Hi Everyone,**

Perhaps it's a simple and/or stupid issue but as it driving me mad I post.

I have a **Listview** with a **custom ArrayAdapter** in a class named CoursFindAdapter and the getView is like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
this.parent = parent;

if(convertView == null){
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cours_find,parent, false);
}


final Cours cours = getItem(position);
telephone = cours.getTelephone();
email = cours.getEmail();
latitude = (long)cours.getLatitude();
longitude = (long)cours.getLongitude();
code = cours.getCode();
id_cours = cours.getId();
tarif = String.valueOf(cours.getTarif());
specialite = cours.getSpecialite();
prenom = cours.getPrenom();
nom = cours.getNom();
titre = cours.getTitre();
description = cours.getDescription();
reserve = cours.getReserve();



SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences(
        "com.learnys.android", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String container = "com.learnys.android.id";
id_etudiant = prefs.getString(container, "0");




CoursViewHolder viewHolder = (CoursViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
if(viewHolder == null){
    viewHolder = new CoursViewHolder();
    viewHolder.titre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titre);
    viewHolder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    viewHolder.codepostal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.codepostal);
    viewHolder.ville = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ville);
    viewHolder.tarif = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tarif);
    viewHolder.nom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
    viewHolder.prenom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prenom);
    viewHolder.specialite = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.specialite);
    viewHolder.distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    viewHolder.choice = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice);

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
}else {
    viewHolder = (CoursViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}


viewHolder.titre.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Cours: </font> " + cours.getTitre() + " </body><html>"));
viewHolder.description.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Description: </font> "+cours.getDescription()+" </body><html>"));
viewHolder.codepostal.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Code Postal: </font> "+String.valueOf(cours.getCodepostal())+" </body><html>"));
viewHolder.ville.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Ville: </font> "+cours.getVille()+" </body><html>"));
viewHolder.tarif.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Tarif: </font> "+String.valueOf(cours.getTarif())+" </body><html>"));
viewHolder.nom.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Nom Professeur: </font> "+cours.getNom()+" </body><html>"));
viewHolder.prenom.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Prénom Professeur: </font> " + cours.getPrenom() + " </body><html>"));
viewHolder.specialite.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Spécialité Professeur: </font> "+cours.getSpecialite()+" </body><html>"));
viewHolder.distance.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font size=10 color=red>Distance: </font> " + cours.getDistance() + " <font size=10 color=red>Temps: </font> " + cours.getTime()  + " </body><html>"));


if (cours.getEtudiant() == Integer.valueOf(id_etudiant)){
    viewHolder.choice.setText("Cours réservé");
    viewHolder.choice.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    ///viewHolder.code.setClickable(false);
    viewHolder.choice.setEnabled(false);
}else {

    viewHolder.choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Activity origin = (Activity) getContext();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(origin, PayPalActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("id_cours", id_cours);
            myIntent.putExtra("id_etudiant", id_etudiant);
            myIntent.putExtra("tarif", tarif);
            myIntent.putExtra("specialite", specialite);
            myIntent.putExtra("description", description);
            myIntent.putExtra("prenom", prenom);
            myIntent.putExtra("nom", nom);
            myIntent.putExtra("telephone", telephone);
            myIntent.putExtra("email", email);
            myIntent.putExtra("titre", titre);
            myIntent.putExtra("code", code);
            myIntent.putExtra("cours", cours);
            getContext().startActivity(myIntent);


        }


    });

}

return convertView;
}
```

The view holder class:

```
public class CoursViewHolder{
public TextView titre;
public TextView description;
public TextView codepostal;
public TextView ville;
public TextView tarif;
public TextView nom;
public TextView prenom;
public TextView specialite;
public String email;
public String telephone;
public long latitude;
public long longitude;
public String code;
public Button choice;
public TextView distance;
}
```

Populated by another class like this:

```
CoursFindAdapter adapter = new CoursFindAdapter(getActivity(),  
cours,getActivity(), page);
adapter.setContext(getActivity());
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The XML of custom adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Titre"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/description"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Description"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titre"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ville"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Ville"
    android:layout_below="@+id/description"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tarif"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Tarif"
    android:layout_below="@+id/codepostal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Nom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tarif"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tarif"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tarif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prenom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Prenom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nom"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nom"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nom" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/specialite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Specialité"
    android:layout_below="@+id/prenom"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/prenom"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/prenom" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Distance"
    android:layout_below="@+id/specialite"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/specialite"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/specialite" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choisir"
    android:id="@+id/choice"
    style="@style/MaterialButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/choice"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<TextView
    tools:text="Code Postal"
    android:id="@+id/codepostal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ville"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And **every time I click** on the **button named choice** inside an item of the list **the data post to the PayPalActivity class is always the data related to the next ID on the list**. Sometimes but not really often it is taking the right data (only on the first item of the list).

I'm shure I'm doing something wrong; implementation, XML or something else I can't figure it out because I use a similar code on another activity and it is as not expected working fine :-(

I tried a lot of things including dispalying the whole data with the remove of this part of code without success:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(reserve) == 1 && cours.getEtudiant() != Integer.valueOf(id_etudiant)) {
    convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else if (cours.getEtudiant() == Integer.valueOf(id_etudiant)){
    viewHolder.choice.setText("Cours réservé");
    viewHolder.choice.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    ///viewHolder.code.setClickable(false);
    viewHolder.choice.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Im' stuck in my stupidity and I don't know what to do now, Any help would be very appreciated.

[EDIT] I notice that if I am on a certain position (not displaying any pixel of the next item on the list) the result is OK but I think it is not a correct behaviour: the correct behavior should be : 'one button choice of the item' should drive the whole item's data even if the item is not displayed completely (the important thing is the button related to an item)
**Regards to all and thank you for reading this issue :-)**

Comment: You didn't add code from `getItem()`, it seems the issue is there.

Comment: this invisible row is messing with your list, it seems. I suggest you, instead, to subtract by one the value returned by `getCount()` and put the hiding logic in `getItem()` so the item you want to hide is never returned

Comment: But I remove the exclusion and the behavior is similar. But you are right I should remove it from the dataset and not on the view after...

Comment: @Abbas I didn't understand your answer could you  be more specific ?

Comment: I removed "if (Integer.valueOf(reserve) == 1 && cours.getEtudiant() != Integer.valueOf(id_etudiant)) {
    convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}" and same issue. When I play with the scroll I am able to have the right one after the wrong one and it is depending from the position, normally it should'nt work like that !

Comment: @Abbas I added     `@Override
    public Cours getItem(int position) {
    Cours        cours = (Cours)getItem(position);
    return  cours;
    }`but i gives me a stackoverflow error...

Comment: @Abbas so I added `@Override
    public Cours getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
    }` but same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simple: you are using outdated data in your `onClickListener()`.

So all you need to do is

```
viewHolder.choice.setTag(position);
viewHolder.choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Cours c = getItem((int) view.getTag());
        Activity origin = (Activity) getContext();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(origin, PayPalActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("id_cours", c.getId());
        myIntent.putExtra("id_etudiant", id_etudiant);
        myIntent.putExtra("tarif", String.valueOf(c.getTarif()));
        myIntent.putExtra("specialite", c.getSpecialite());
        myIntent.putExtra("description", c.getDescription());
        .
        .
        .
        myIntent.putExtra("cours", c);
        getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Whats happening is your data gets updated each time `getView()` is called i.e. until all the views are laid out. When you click an item values are changed. So you are getting the last values from the `getView()` iteration.

Also instead of getting all the fields from `cours` you might want to use `cours.getId()`, etc. this I'm sure is not affecting your performance that much.

Comment: @exaju If the answer helped you then please mark it as correct, so others can find the correct answer.

Comment: Here it is. I didn't understood that a +1 was not equal to accept solution... Many thanks another time :-)